# Test embedded code by replacing static symbols at compile time

Tags: c, compilation, linker, arm

**Background**

I'm building a C application for an embedded Cortex M4 TI-RTOS SYS/BIOS target, however this question should apply to all embedded targets where a single binary is loaded onto some microprocessor.

**What I want**

I'd like to do some in situ regression tests on the target where I just replace a single function with some test function instead. E.g. a GetAdcMeasurement() function would return predefined values from a read-only array instead of doing the actual measurement and returning that value.

This could of course be done with a mess of #ifndefs, but I'd rather keep the production code as untouched as possible.

**My attempt**

I figure one way to achieve this would be to have duplicate symbol definitions at the linker stage, and then have the linker prioritise the definitions from the test suite (given some #define).

I've looked into using LD_PRELOAD, but that doesn't really seem to apply here (since I'm using only static objects).

**Details**

I'm using TI Code Composer, with TI-RTOS & SYS/BIOS on the Sitara AM57xx platform, compiling for the M4 remote processor (denoted IPU1). 
Here's the path to the compiler and linker

```
/opt/ti/ccsv7/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-arm_16.9.6.LTS/bin/armcl
```

Comment: I'm also digging for a solution in the compiler manual http://downloads.ti.com/docs/esd/SPNU151M/index.html#SPNU151M_HTML/linking-c-c-code.html#4_Linking_C_C++_Code%3FTocPath%3D4%2520Linking%2520C%252FC%252B%252B%2520Code%7C_____0

Comment: If you used GCC, the usual way would be to use the weak attribute, but I cannot see this mentioned in your compiler manual. I.e. your standard functions would be weak but still resolved by the linker unless you provide a strong mock function. [Mimick](https://github.com/diacritic/Mimick) works by poisoning the [GOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Offset_Table) which also works for dynamic modules only.

Comment: @Groo would this be the #pragma WEAK (symbol) directive? http://downloads.ti.com/docs/esd/SPNU151M/index.html#SPNU151M_HTML/arm-c-c-language-implementation.html#STDZ0556591

Comment: Hey, yes, this seem to be the same thing! Perhaps you can try it and then post your own answer if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(This is a quick sum up the discussion in the comments, thanks for answers)*

A function can be redefined if it has the weak attribute, see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol

On GCC that would be the weak attribute, e.g.

```
int __attribute__((weak)) power2(int x);
```

and on the armcl (as in my question) that would be the pragma directive

```
#pragma weak power2

int power2(int x);
```

Letting the production code consist of partly weak functions will allow a test framework to replace single functions.

Comment: FYI: This is the accepted answer, but I have to wait 2 days for it. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to have multiple .c files for each module, one the production code and one the test code, and compile and link with one of the two. The globals and function signatures in both .c file must be at least the same (at least: there may be more symbols but not less).

Another solution, building on the previous one, is to have two libraries, one with the production code and one with the test code, and link with one of both. You could ieven link with both lubraries, with the test version first, as linkers often resolve symbols in the order they are encountered.

And, as you said, you could work with a bunch of `#ifdef`s, which would have the advantage of having just one .c file, but making tyhe code less readable.

I would not go for `#ifdef`s on the function level, i.e. defining just one function of a .c file for test and keeping the others as is; however, if necessary, it could be away. And if necessary, you could have one .c file (two) for each function, but that would negate the module concept.

I think the first approach would be the cleanest.

Comment: Solution #1 is actually used in the code when the whole HAL-layer is stubbed, but now I'd like to keep all the other things chugging along, which makes it a bit impractical. 
I'll consider the other ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One additional approach (apart from Paul Ogilvie's) would be to have your mocking header also create a define which will replace the original function symbol at the pre-processing stage.

I.e. if your mocking header looks like this:

```
// mock.h

#ifdef MOCKING_ENABLED

  adcdata_t GetAdcMeasurement_mocked(void);
  stuff_t   GetSomeStuff_mocked(void);

  #define GetAdcMeasurement GetAdcMeasurement_mocked
  #define GetSomeStuff GetSomeStuff_mocked

#endif
```

Then whenever you include the file, the preprocessor will replace the calls before it even hits the compiler:

```
#include "mock.h"

void SomeOtherFunc(void)
{
    // preprocessor will change this symbol into 'GetAdcMeasurement_mocked'
    adcdata_t data = GetAdcMeasurement();
}
```

The approach might confuse the unsuspected reader of your code, because they won't necessarily realize that you are calling a different function altogether. Nevertheless, I find this approach to have the least impact to the production code (apart from adding the include, obviously).

Comment: I just had the same idea myself, and I think it's the next-best thing to the #pragma weak (haven't tried yet). Thanks for both ideas!

Comment: @vindarmagnus: NP, although I think if you get the weak directive working, it would be better to post your own answer and accept it to help future readers.

Comment: Sure, I will do that.